# How to exclude multple keys from my selection

Tags: jquery, filter, key

why can i not do this:

```
$(elem).children().filter(':not(:eq(0,1))').doStuff();
```

how can i exclude multiple keys from my selection??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they're all from the beginning, then this would work:

```
$(elem).children().slice(2).doStuff();
```

Otherwise, this could work:

```
var exclude = [2,5];

$(elem)
.children()
.filter(function(i){ return exclude.indexOf(i) === -1; })
.doStuff();
```

Which you could turn into a nice plugin:

```
$.fn.exclude = function(){
   var args = arguments;
   return this.filter(function(i){ return args.indexOf(i) === -1; });
};

$(elem).children().exclude(0,3,8).doStuff();
```

Could do better type handling and optimisations but that's the idea.

Comment: what if i wanted to exclude key 0 and key 8, but not everything in between?

Comment: @Esben, you could filter them